# Can prey go inside lodges?

Tags: the-hunter

I've been tracking a mule deer for 3000m+ (it just won't give me a break) And now the most fresh track I found points (for the most of it) inside a lodge. Given the huge area to cover (i'm still in a "far track" state), should I just ignore all the lodge area ? Can deer, or prey in general, go inside lodge areas ?

Answer (score 2):

Well I've found track of that same deer inside the lodge area (mainly at the entrace road and at the shooting range, which are boat in the lodge area). I could open the lodge inventory at these place so I guess that YES, prey can go inside lodges.

PS : I ended up giving up on that deer, the last track I found leaded to the previous one and I ended up going back and forth on the beach between the same two tracks numerous times (it had a fleeing status so maybe it found a way to "lose me").

Answer (score 0):

Yes, animals do generally wander into the lodge areas, it's not a bug at all, I'd say if it's quiet enough... why not :D The last fox I shot ran back to the lodge I spawned in and he had ran and died right there on the campfire... what a good fox... cooking himself up for when I get there :D